# WCF Client does not work with HTTPS

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have a webservice running on a server over both http and https and I can view the WSDL from my other machine just fine over either protocol.

However, in code, when I call it, I get a 404 for the https call (http is fine). This is what I have done:

1. Consumed the webservice
2. Set the url
3. Made a call

Is there anything else I need to do? the only thing I've changed is the url from http to https. Here's a sample of the auto generated code and my call in Reference.cs:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="BasicHttpBinding_WebServiceSoap", Namespace="http://www.example.com/WebInterface")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DLFormBaseType))]

 public partial class Scanning : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
```

I call it like this:

```
using (Scanning ws = new Scanning())
{
    ws.Url = url;
    //web service call
}
```

where url is just the fully qualified url to the web service.

Comment: You need to set up a https WebServiceBindingAttribute.

Comment: thanks. Where do I put this? how does that work? that sounds like something for my Reference.cs file, but that was system generated. And how are you supposed to support http and https?

Comment: and there is one, as my code, is there something wrong with this?

[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="BasicHttpBinding_WebServiceSoap", Namespace="http://www.example.com/WebInterface")]

Comment: That's a basic http binding not a https binding. I *think* you'd put in the same place. Not 100% sure as our code isn't set up this way.

Comment: I read this
http://benjii.me/2012/08/setting-up-a-soap-webservice-with-ssl-using-configurationless-wcf/

and it says configurationless WCF is fine, but won't work with https. I don't know how true this is, but it's a shedload of code and I can't believe something as simple as changing to https needs so much work doing to a VS project...